# Why won't mariadb listen on port 3306 after a macports update?

Tags: macports, mariadb

At some point after a mariadb port update, she refused to listen on 3306 upon startup.

I made sure there were no skip-networking directives, and even tried adding one with "=OFF", which did nothing... but the odd thing was it *had* been working, and "I haven't changed anything".

Yet when I run:

`/opt/local/lib/mariadb/bin/mysqladmin variables -u root -p | grep skip_networking`

I see skip-networking as being ON.

My config has this:

```
[mysqld]
port            = 3306  
bind-address    = 127.0.0.1
```

and no skip-networking setting at all.

Even passing the port and bind-address via command line will not make it listen.

Answer (score 4):

After a grep of /opt/local/etc, it turns out there is a default config, and inside that there's a skip-networking directive:

`cat /opt/local/etc/mariadb/macports-default.cnf`

This was only picked up because after reading /etc/my.cnf, apparently the /opt/local/etc/mariadb/my.cnf file is also read.  (I'd used /etc/my.cnf, never having edited the other, but something changed-- maybe I'd edited the default and it was overwritten with the update, though I don't remember doing so.)

Commenting out the include in `/opt/local/etc/mariadb/my.cnf` of the macports-default.cnf once again has her listening.

Pretty clear solution in retrospect I guess, but I was a bit stumped, as I swear "I changed nothing!"...  Regardless-- For posterity, and key word searches!

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment yet, but wanted to add:

If you have other versions of MySQL or mariaDB installed via MacPorts, be sure to check out their config files too because MariaDB reads them.

*Locations:*

`/opt/local/etc/mysql${mysqlVersion}/my.cnf`

`/opt/local/etc/mariadb-${mariadbVersion}/my.cnf`

I have mariadb-10.1-server installed. *There are two configs:*

`/opt/local/etc/mariadb/my.cnf`

`/opt/local/etc/mariadb-${mariadbVersion}/my.cnf`

Additionally, some info about default config files from MirandaDB [documentation](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/mysqld-configuration-files-and-groups/) (this is *not* Macports specific):

1. `/etc/my.cnf`
2. `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`
3. `my.cnf` in the `DEFAULT_SYSCONFDIR` specified during the compilation
4. `my.cnf` in the path, specified in the environment variable `MYSQL_HOME` (if any) the file specified in `--defaults-extra-file` (if any)
5. `user-home-dir/.my.cnf`

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively to commenting out the defaults file, the value can be overriden in the `my.cnf`:

```
[mysqld]
...
skip_networking=0
```